# Error with std::copy in copy constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, copy-constructor

I'm writing my own `vector` class just to have an understanding of how memory management works. The only place in the class that I'm calling `std::copy` from is in the copy constructor.

```
vector::vector(const vector& v)
        :sz{v.sz}, space{v.space}, elem{new double[sz]}
    {
        copy(v.elem, v.elem + v.sz, elem);
    }
```

where sz(int)  is the size of the vector, space(int) is the memory reserved for the vector and elem(double*) is a pointer to elements.

When I call `std::copy` i get the following error.

```
Error   C4996   'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be
unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are  
correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See  
documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'  Project2    
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 2230
```

Have i missed something in that I'm not passing the proper parameter?

Comment: The std::copy() algorithm expects a start iterator, an end iterator and an output iterator as parameters. When you are defining your own container, you should also implement a way to iterate through the container. This is especially if you plan to use some of the inbuilt algorithms such as std::copy(). Else, you can write your own copy method which takes in pointers rather than iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct. Apparently you're using some funky compiler option that turns warnings into errors. The warning is saying that the implementation of `copy` can't check that it isn't copying past the end of the destination array. But the calling code (your copy constructor) has checked that already, so there's no problem with the call.

Comment: Thank you, thought I made a mistake somewhere.